# Is there an XML doc view in Visual Studio similar to the JavaDoc view in Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Eclipse, there's a JavaDoc View which would display the JavaDoc of whatever the current or last selected element was. I'm trying to find something similar for C# in Visual Studio 2013, but I'm not seeing anything like is. Does it exist? If so how do I activate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. In Visual Studio, one would use the "Object Browser" to get something similar to the JavaDoc view. To get to it, View->Object Browser.

It does behave differently than Eclipse's JavaDoc view. Rather than tying the documentation to the cursor in the edit view, the Object Browser has a search box where one could search for the object they wish to view documentation on.

Answer (score 2):

There are many applications that can generate MSDN style documentation from your XML comments. Here are a few I have used and they work well

VSdocman:
http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html

SandCastle
http://sandcastle.codeplex.com

Comment: Thank you for the links. What I was hoping for is something more real time. In Eclipse, I can click on an element and it will display its javadoc in the javadoc view regardless if it's a referenced prebuilt source-jar or something in the source code.